# Call method of Objects, that are instances of Interface

Tags: java, interface, instanceof

I have an Array of `ClassA`, which implements no interfaces. But there is a `ClassB` and a `ClassC`, which both implements the interface `InterfaceA`. `InterfaceA` looks like this:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    int methodA();
}
```

Now I want to iterate through my Array of Instances of `ClassA` (which also contains some Instances of `ClassB` and `ClassC`) and I want to get the sum of every result of `methodA()`.

At runtime, the following code should work (imO):

```
myArray = new ObjectA[10];

// how the Array gets it's content is irrelevant here

int result = 0;
for (final ObjectA a : myArray) {
    if (a instanceof InterfaceA) {
        result += a.methodA();
    }
}
```

But since `ClassA` does not necessarily have a `methodA()`, my Compiler is unhappy about it. It thinks, `a.methodA()` is not defined, because the compiler doesn't know about the if condition. So, in case you don't implement an abstract `methodA()` to `ClassA`, what would you do?

Comment: You could cast?

Comment: did you mean `result += ((InterfaceA)a).methodA();`?

Comment: else you can try: if (a instanceof InterfaceA && !a.getClass().getName().equals(ClassA)) {}

Comment: the if condition is not the main problem - it works fine. The only problem is, that my compiler doesn't know that every 'a' inside the if condition has a defined 'methodA()'.

Comment: Yes, thats why I did modification to the if condition. In the IF condition I am telling your program that ClassA has no implementation of methodA()

Comment: I would go out an limb here and suggest the following. Why not turn the interface method to a defender/default one and just do an implements on ClassA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use cast to make your compiler happy. In your code the methodA is called on an `a` which can be an instance of ClassA, or ClassB or anything else.
As you are already restricting non interfaceA instances from reaching in the IF block you can use type cast.

```
for (final ObjectA a : myArray) {
    if (a instanceof InterfaceA) {
        result += ((InterfaceA)a).methodA();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that works. Thanks a lot! Just one more question: Why do I need both braces around InterfaceA and (InterfaceA)a ?

Comment: It has to do with the way how Java evaluates expressions. You want to **first cast** and then use the method. If you leave it away, it will try to first use the method on `a` and then cast on the result of the method. And the braces around the `InterfaceA` are how you specify a **cast** in Java.